# React Native CodePush different key for the 'Production' deployment

Tags: react-native, code-push

My app is linked with the 'Staging' deployment key '**sss**'. It's defined at `/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`, under `reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey`.

Now when I actually release an APK, I'd like to use the 'Production' deployment key '**ppp**'.

What's the best way to do that? How do I automate it, so it knows it should use the 'ppp' key? I use the `./gradlew assembleRelease` command to build the APK.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do this would be to use a build type resource override.
If your build types are `debug` and `release`, you would put a strings.xml file at `/android/app/src/release/res/values/strings.xml` with only the one key `reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey` with a value of `ppp`

Another possible way to do this, if you didn't want to commit your prod key to your repo would be to place it in an environment variable.

1. Your Gradle file would have to read the env var:

   `def codePushKey = System.getenv("CODEPUSH_KEY") ?: "sss"`
2. Add the env var to your BuildConfig dynamically

   ```
   buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled true
               debuggable false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               signingConfig signingConfigs.config
               buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", codePushKey
           }
   ```
3. Replace your CodePush instantiation with the BuildConfig var instead of a string resource.
   In your `ReactNativeHost` implementation, in the `getPackages()` override, update the CodePush instantiation to:

`new CodePush(BuildConfig.CODEPUSH_KEY, getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)`